# How to append unicode ranging U+0000 to U+0099 to NSString in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How to append `unicode` ranging  `U+0000`  to `U+0099` To  NSString in iOS. I have used the following link for reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: For a string literal? What have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690172/xcode-utf-8-literals a NUL character is not supported within a string (it indicates the terminator of the string). If, however you're actually trying to construct binary data, then a string is not the correct data type for that

Comment: What do you mean by "add" them?  Append them to an existing string?  Or put them into a literal NSString?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one....

`NSString` uses UTF-16 to store codepoints internally, so those in the range you're looking for (U+1F300 to U+1F6FF) will be stored as a [surrogate pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) (four bytes). Despite its name, characterAtIndex: (and unichar) doesn't know about codepoints and will give you the two bytes that it sees at the index you give it (the 55357 you're seeing is the lead surrogate of the codepoint in UTF-16).

To examine the raw codepoints, you'll want to convert the string/characters into UTF-32 (which encodes them directly). To do this, you have a few options:

1)    Get all UTF-16 bytes that make up the codepoint, and use either [this algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/faq//utf_bom.html#utf16-3) or [CFStringGetLongCharacterForSurrogatePair](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringGetLongCharacterForSurrogatePair) to convert the surrogate pairs to UTF-32.

2)    Use either dataUsingEncoding: or `getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:` to convert the NSString to UTF-32, and interpret the raw bytes as a uint32_t.

3)    Use a library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is 100% correct solution, but it works:

```
NSString *uniString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unichar)0x0021];
```

Where `0x0021` is your unicode char code.

You can test it with this loop:

```
for (unichar ch = 0x0000; ch <= 0x0099; ch++) {
    NSString *uniString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", ch];
    NSLog(@"%@", uniString);
}
```