# Universal character name error in NSString when using unicode character, <

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

I'd like to use the Unicode version of '<' in an NSString but the compiler produces the error:

```
"Character '<' cannot be specified by a universal character name"
```

when I use:

```
NSString *text = @"Some Text: \u003C";
```

'<' seems to be a special character, as well as "=" and a few others so what's a way to insert a literal '<' inside the string, without literally using `'<'` like so: `"some string <"`?

I don't have control over the string value itself and the above value as in-line is for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Well, `NSString *text = @"Some Text: >";`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Maybe Will needs a framework for converting Unicode Codepoints into regular characters

Comment: I don't have control over the text value - so < won't work.

Comment: @Will What do you mean by "not having control over the text value"?

Comment: The value is coming in from a text file that will have unicode values embedded with standard English text. Ex: Hello \u003C

Comment: Weird. I just tried and a similar errors appears for many different values such as `\u0020` (space) or `\u0041\` (A).

Comment: @rmaddy - Yes it is weird, but also defined that way in the Standard "A universal character name shall not specify a character whose short identifier is less than 00A0 other than 0024 ($), 0040 (@), or 0060 (‘), nor one in the range D800 through DFFF inclusive." The Standard doesn't say *why* they came up with this restriction.

Comment: @CRD any webpage you can refer ? to read more about this. This concept is still going over my head

Comment: @114100웃 - I quoted the C11 ISO Standard, section 6.4.3 Universal character names, paragraph 2 Constraints. If you search for N1570 you should find PDF copies of the (draft) Standard on the web - or you can buy a PDF of the final version from ISO. The paragraph has the footnote: "The disallowed characters are the characters in the basic character set and the code positions reserved by ISO/IEC 10646 for control characters, the character DELETE, and the S-zone (reserved for use by UTF−16)." but that doesn't explain the *reasoning* for disallowing hex forms of characters that can be typed. HTH.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*I don't believe that the compiler error was addressed.*

## In response to the errors:

```
"Character '<' cannot be specified by a universal character name"
"Universal character name refers to a control character"
```

it appears that you cannot use the `\U000000xx` literal syntax for many 2 bytes ASCII characters, with the following exceptions:

- `\U00000024`
- `\U00000040`
- `\U00000060`
- `\U000000A0` to `\U000000FF`

A simple workaround is to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x000000xx]`

*Example with the '<' character:*

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %C", 0x003C]";
```

See [xcode UTF-8 literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690172/xcode-utf-8-literals) for more options.

Answer (score 4):

If the string has been read from a text file containing "Hello \u003C" with a *verbatim
backslash* then you would have

```
NSString *text = @"Hello \\u003C";
```

If the text file contains only ASCII characters then
you can use the fact that `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` decodes "\uNNNN" to the corresponding Unicode character:

```
NSData *data = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *converted = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

*Added:* You probably can create the string directly from the file with

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];
```

and all the Unicode escape sequences are already properly converted.

Comment: I'll try this - any explanation on why I can't put the string directly in an .m file, as demonstrated in the sample code?

Comment: @Will: As I understand your comments to the question, the text file contains a backslash character. To put a backslash character into a literal string or NSString, it has to be escaped as "\\".

Comment: I guess I don't understand why I can use some unicode characters but not all inside an NSString without escaping it. This is accepted by clang: @"Hello \u02C4 \u0502 \u0024" whereas this is not: @"Hello \u02C4 \u0502 \u0024 \u003C";

Comment: @Will: See CRD's comment to the question. - But you said that you read the string from a text file, so you don't have a literal string anyway.

Comment: I did but because the code version gives warnings, it has piqued my curiosity and if at some point, I want to define it inline, I'd like to understand the problem better.

Comment: @Will: `@"\u0024"` is *identical* to `@"$"` (one character). As CRD said, `"\uNNNN"` is allowed by the standard only for certain characters, and we don't know why. - But if you have a file containing the characters "\u0024" and read that into an NSString, then the NSString would be `@"\\u0024"` (5 characters, the backslash is escaped). Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: thank you for the NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding suggestion! Saved me a huge headache  :)

Answer (score 4):

clang follows the C standard here, which for some reason disallows this:

> C99 6.4.3p2: A universal character name shall not specify a character whose short identifier is less than 00A0 other than 0024 ($), 0040 (@), or 0060 (`), nor one in the range D800 through DFFF inclusive.)