# Is there a way to have double-quotation marks in strings in Objective C without escaping them?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to have double-quotation marks in strings in Objective C without escaping them?

In PHP you can wrap a string in single quotation marks, in which case you do not have to escape anything in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only chance is to compile your source as Objective-C++ file
(file suffix ".mm"). Then the [C++ raw string literals](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/10/16/cpp-11-raw-strings-literals-tutorial/) are also accepted when defining an `NSString`,
for example

```
NSString *str = @R"(Hello"World\n)";
```

has the 13 characters

```
H e l l o " W o r l d \ n
```

But that feature is only available in (Objective-)C++ source files,
not in (Objective-)C.

Comment: Awesome! An answer from on high

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way (that I know of) to have an unescaped quotation mark inside a string in Objective-C. You can get a quotation mark using unicode or some other trick, but I believe that you want a less ugly way to write a quotation inside a string, not an even uglier one :)

P.S. Just for fun I've just tried to use a unicode escape sequence (`@"\u0022"`), and it turned out [it is forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155210/universal-character-name-error-in-nsstring-when-using-unicode-character).

Comment: The preprocessor converts `\uxxxx` escapes to their actual characters before the compiler does its job. So `@"\u0022"` ends up being the same as `@"""`. So you need the backslash in both cases.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you for the explanation) I didn't know it is done at the preprocessor level before. It explains why it is forbidden. There is a catch however. Xcode just refuses to compile "incorrect" escape sequences, without trying to replace them. Otherwise `@"\u005c\u0022"` would work. And if we just add a backslash (`@"\\u0022"`), the string will be treated as a plaintext: `"\u0022"`. "How hard can it be to use unicode for quotes inside a string?" :)

Comment: @rmaddy, that's not true. You can ask for the preprocessor output (e.g. using `cc -E`) and `\uxxxx` escape sequences in string literals remain. It's the compiler which handles those.

Answer (score -1):

Curly quotes don't require escaping, and generally look better for messages presented to the end user:

```
    NSString *str = @"Hello, “World”!";
```

Comment: It's for a JSON string so can't use curlies.