# Objective-C / C Convert UTF8 Literally to Real string

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, utf-8

Im wondering how to convert

```
NSString = "\xC4"; ....
```

to real NSString represented in normal format

Comment: What do you mean with "real NSString" and "normal format"?

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally related to [xcode UTF-8 literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690172/xcode-utf-8-literals).  Of course, it is ambiguous what you actually mean by "\xC4" - without an encoding specified, it means nothing.

If you mean the character whose Unicode code point is 0x00C4 then I would think (though I haven't tested) that this will do what you want.

NSString *s = @"\u00C4";

Answer (score 0):

First are you sure you have `\xC4` in your string? Consider:

```
NSString *one = @"\xC4\x80";
NSString *two = @"\\xC4\\x80";
NSLog(@"%@ | %@", one, two);
```

This will output:

```
Ā | \xC4\x80
```

If you are certain your string contains the four characters `\xC4` are you sure it is UTF-8 encoded as ASCII? Above you will see I added `\x80`, this is because `\xC4` is not valid UTF-8, it is the first byte of a two-byte sequence. Maybe you have only shown a sample of your input and the second byte is present, if not you do not have UTF-8 encoded as ASCII.

If you are certain it is UTF-8 encoded as ASCII you will have to convert it yourself. It might seem the Cocoa string encoding methods would handle it, especially as what you appear to have is a string as it might be written in Objective-C source code. Unfortunately the obvious encoding, `NSNonLossyAsciiStringEncoding` only handles octal and unicode escapes, not the hexadecimal escapes in your string.

You can use any algorithm you like to convert it. One choice would be a simple *finite state machine* which scans the input a byte at a time and recognises the four byte sequence: `\`, `x`, `hex-digit`, `hex-digit`; and combines the two hex-digits into a single byte. `NSString` is not the best choice for byte-at-time string processing, you may be better off converting to C strings, e.g.:

```
// sample input, all characters should be ASCII
NSString *input = @"\\xC4\\x80"; 

// obtain a C string containing the ASCII characters
const char *cInput = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 

// allocate a buffer of the correct length for the result
char cOutput[strlen(c2a)+1];

// call your function to decode the hexadecimal escapes
convertAsciiEncodedUTF8(cInput, cOutput);

// create a NSString from the result
NSString *output = [NSString stringWithCString:cOutput encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You just need to write the finite state machine, or other algorithm, for `convertAsciiEncodedUTF8`.

*(If you write an algorithm and it fails ask another question showing your code, somebody will probably help you. But don't expect someone to write it for you.)*

HTH